# squeeze theorem on a factorial

Tags: calculus

Consider the sequence $\{\frac{x^n}{n!}\}_n$ for any number $x$.

By choosing $m>x$ and letting $n>m$ , show that:

$\frac{x^n}{n!} < \frac{x^n}{m^n} < \frac{m^m}{(m-1)!}$

Am using the squeeze theorem , but unable to start third inequality.

Comment: sorrry lost parts the limit  as n appraches infinity = 0

Comment: I think you actually need $m>\lvert x\rvert$ for the upper bound to hold ($x=-1000,\ m=2,\ n=3$).

Comment: Or, if you're interested in asymptotic extimations, $x=-1000,\ m=2,\ n\text{ even}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only see two inequalities there.  If the last is your problem, maybe you can show $\frac{x^n}{m^n} \lt 1 \lt \frac{m^m}{(m-1)!}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $n > m \geq 1$, then $m^n \geq m^{m-1} \geq (m-1)!$.

But the *first* inequality does not look right.
Let $x = 1$,  $m = 3>x$, and $n = 4 > m$.
Then

$$\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{24} \not< \frac{1}{81} = \frac{x^n}{m^n}.$$

In fact, in general I don't think the inequality works if $n$ is just
a little bit greater than $m$.

Perhaps the problem as originally posed says something different than
the version copied here.
But the first inequality is true if $n$ is *much* greater than $m$,
so you didn't just copy the first inequality backward.